# Is it possible to use the tex-dvi-ps-pdf route with luatex?

Tags: luatex, pstricks, psfrag, dvi-mode

This question should be of general interest. It is triggered by the Japanese edition of my free physics text (see http://www.motionmountain.net/japanese.html ), where lualatex (from TexLive 2017) would be better than pdflatex. Because in the latex code I use

- pstricks,
- dozens of psfrags,
- hundreds of eps figures,
- dozens of \specials, and
- many embedded films with movie15,
- and a large .cls files with more than 4000 lines of code,

I need to use the tex-dvi-ps-pdf conversion sequence. Can this sequence be used with lua(la)tex?

In pdflatex, the tex-dvi-ps-pdf route can be enforced by setting \pdfoutput=0 and using dvips and then a ps to pdf converter such as ps2pdf or Distiller.

Is this also possible in lua(la)tex? Lualatex does not recognize the command \pdfoutput=0 .

Comment: Does `lualatex --output-format=dvi` help?

Comment: When using TeX Live, there might be a command named "dvilualatex". (\outputmode=0 of LuaTeX is equivalent of \pdfoutput=0.) And, one more thing: The most recent version of LuaLaTeX requires luaotfload (and the fone encoding is set to TU not OT1), and the usage of its extended font selection scheme is not recognized by dvips. You should add \usepackage[OT1]{fontenc} to avoid errors of dvips.

Comment: Why do you want to use LuaTeX? OpenType fonts? Afaik, they are not supported by dvips.

Comment: Btw: Have you tried `auto-pst-pdf` etc.?

Comment: I think it's probably worth noting that LuaTeX development is very much PDF-focussed: I would be wary of using DVI mode for _new_ projects with this engine. (That doesn't of course prevent you using it in the case in hand.)

Comment: what is auto-pst-pdf and where/how is it used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, as given by TeXnician, to use

```
lualatex --output-format=dvi
```

Comment: Just a note on our usual etiquette: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/what-if-a-comment-answers-a-question :)

Comment: One might also use just `dvilualatex` (which is the same thing, really).

Comment: You could also use `\outputmode=0` in the document, but I don't see what you would gain by using lualatex.  As Heiko mentioned in its comment: Open type fonts won't work in dvi-mode, and so you don't simplify the japanese.

Comment: this is at best a partial answer as you were suggested luatex in the earlier question so as to use japanese opentype fonts and if you use dvi output from luatex then you will not be able to process such fonts with any standard dvi driver,.